# add and remove the " " symbols from string in swift

Tags: ios, swift, string

[image]

I want add the " " symbols to my text data. text data is getting from textview. 
I want remove the " " symbols from optional text. optional text is getting from text filed, how to remove and how to add the "" symbols in swift.......

Comment: search for optionals swift in google

Comment: Please read [Swift Language Guide: The Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25591241/swift-remove-character-from-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the string you are trying to log is typed as an optional (`String?`) rather than just a `String`. You need to unwrap it before logging it.

You can either use `if let`:

```
if let string = maybeString {
    print(string)
}
```

Or (and this is what I prefer), you can use the `??` operator to provide a placeholder value to print in the case of the string being `nil`:

```
print(string ?? "(nil)")
```

Comment: I have compare the both values

Comment: textdata for RFID device and optional values from my json id I have to compare Both datas like  let dataval  = kid.cardNo if self.textdata == dataval but its not working because of this symbols if I can specified like self.textdata = "71beda1d" its working

Comment: @naga I'm sorry, I can't understand what you're saying.

Comment: tq for support I can resolve my issue with convert to string its working fine